# Finding the level of the particular node in a hierarchical xml using a node value in .Net

Tags: .net, xml, vb.net, xml-parsing

Finding the level of the particular xml using a node value in .Net

Experts ! This is my sample Xml.This is a tree structure and `T->T.1,T.2->T.2.2,TA->TA.1` - this is the tree strucutre. I know the value of tag . ie 1232,1343.. etc.
Using this ID how can I find that `1343` is coming under `1232`. or `1490` is under `1090` which is again under `1232`. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

**Expected output : if i pass 1490 then I need to know 1490,1090,1232 etc (from that nodeto the top node).I am using .net 2.0**

```
<Abc>
 <A> 
  <Name>T</Name>
  <Id>1232</Id>
  <Val>140</Val>
  <Branch>
   <A>
   <Name>T.1</Name>
  <Id>1343</Id>
  <Val>14qw0</Val>
   </A>
   <A>
   <Name>T.2</Name>
  <Id>1090</Id>
  <Val>14qwd0</Val>
   <Branch>
   <A>
   <Name>T.2.2</Name>
    <Id>1490</Id>
    <Val>rt56</Val>
   </A>
   </Branch>
 </A>
 <A>
   <Name>TA</Name>
    <Id>1339</Id>
    <Val>uiui</Val>
    <Branch>
    <A>
    <Name>TA.1</Name>
        <Id>1338</Id>
        <Val>bije</Val>
    </A>
    </Branch>
</A>
</Abc>
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you parse with Linq to Xml, then simply use the [Ancestors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339717.aspx) method to list its ancestors?

Comment: Can you traverse up the nodes via the ParentNode Property?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.parentnode(v=vs.80).aspx